# Using Variables as .css() Style Property in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a responsive design through jQuery, that will adjust the values of a variety of css style properties depending on the specific page width. Unfortunately, I'm running into troubles when I try to pass a variable into .css() for the style property.

Here's the relevant code:

```
if (screenWidth < maxWidth && screenWidth > minWidth) {
    container.css({stylePropToChange: (minValue + widthPercent) + unit});
    //the problem area is here^^^
} else if (screenWidth >= maxWidth) {
    container.css({stylePropToChange: minValue + unit});
} else {
    container.css({stylePropToChange: maxValue + unit});
}
```

[Full code: jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/34Rd6/1/)

The stylePropToChange variable isn't being recognized as "width" in this code. If I substitute that with just the string "width", like so:

```
container.css({"width": (minValue + widthPercent) + unit});
```

...it now works. Why doesn't jQuery accept the variable on the 'property name' side of .css(), but does accept the variables on the value side?

What can I do to make this work?

In searching for an answer, I found [this question posted in the jquery forums](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/how-to-pass-variables-in-jquery-css), where someone was having a different problem, but they were somehow able to do what I'm trying to do. Am I just missing something simple here?

Comment: not really an answer to your question, but have you thought about using [media queries](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/)? It's considered a best practice and will be less complex than what you're trying to do.

Comment: @tjb1982 Thanks for the comment! Yes, I had thought of that, and I've used it before, so it is always a possibility if I can't get this working.

I just thought it would be cool to design a page that glides into a new layout instead of popping into it. And this way I get to learn more complex material! :)

Comment: http://elliotjaystocks.com/blog/css-transitions-media-queries/

Comment: @tbj1982 That's really interesting; it's not exactly what I'm trying to accomplish, but I'll look at that more in depth tomorrow morning. Thanks for the link, and for your answer below! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't set javascript object properties in that way. Just use:

```
container.css(stylePropToChange, minValue + unit);
```

etc. if you want to keep doing it that way. Incidentally, I don't really understand why you aren't using multiple @media queries in your css to do the same thing. Can you explain why you want to do it in javascript?

Comment: Thanks @awexfwex!

I wanted to do it in Javascript to teach myself some more complex javascript, (I'm pretty new to it) and to get a slick transition from one size to the next, without popping into a new style at specified widths.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `.css()` with an object literal. You cannot use variables as member names in object literals. If you wish to do the same thing but with a variable, do it like this:

```
container.css(string_variable, value_variable);
```

If you absolutely have to use an object literal, you can define it as a variable and add properties to it with the variable as the member name like so, and then pass it into the function:

```
var obj = {};
obj[string_variable] = value_variable;
obj[string_variable2 = value_variable2;

container.css(obj);
```

Comment: Thanks @PitaJ! I should have noticed that... once the object literal was in a jQuery context I just completely glazed over what it was. I'll have to read up on it again to really drill it into my head. Thanks again! :)

Answer (score 0):

The argument to `css()` is an [object literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Object_literals). It's not possible to use a variable to set the property name in an object literal like you tried to do (as you discovered). But you could try to do this instead:

```
var obj = {};
if (screenWidth < maxWidth && screenWidth > minWidth) {
    obj[stylePropToChange] = (minValue + widthPercent) + unit;
    obj[anotherStylePropToChange] = 25;
    container.css(obj);
} else if (screenWidth >= maxWidth) {
    ...
} else {
    ...
}
```

but I would try media queries instead: https://www.google.com/search?q=media+queries+transition